# Is there any way to enable voice over for iPod not using iTunes?

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, music, ipod

I have an iPod shuffle which works fine: I can add and remove songs via Rhythmbox.

According to [Apple page](http://www.apple.com/ipod-shuffle/#voiceover) my iPod is able to talk the name of the songs:

> ### Give your songs a voice.
>
> Say you’re listening to a song and **want to know the title or the artist**. Just press the VoiceOver button on top of your iPod shuffle, and **it tells you**. You can even use VoiceOver to hear the names of playlists and switch between them. And if your battery needs charging, VoiceOver tells you that, too.

From what I know, voice over can be only enabled if I use iTunes. My question is: can I enable voice over only using Ubuntu? How?